# If $f_x$ is $T$-measurable, $f^y$ is $S$-measurable, is $f$ $(S\times T)$-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis Theorem 8.5 states

Let $f$ be an $(S\times T)$-measurable function on $X \times Y$. Then:

a) $\forall x\in X, f_x $ is $T$-measurable function;

b) $\forall y\in Y, f^y $ is $S$-measurable function

where $f_x(y) = f(x,y)$, $f^y(x)=f(x,y)$.

This statement is simple and nice. I am thinking about is inverse also true? That is, if $f_x$ is $T$-measurable, $f^y$ is $S$-measurable, then $f$ is $(S\times T)$-measurable.
Or we need some more strong condition on $f_x$ and $f^y$ to show $f$ is $(S\times T)$-measurable.

Answer (score 2):

The inverse statement is false. Let $E$ be a Vitali-set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Delta$ the diagonal in $\mathbb{R}^2$ Definie $$f(x,y) = 1_{(E \times E) \cap \Delta}(x,y).$$ Then $f^x(y) = 1$ if $x=y$ and $y \in E$, otherwise zero. Thus Borel-measurable, but $f$ is not! (Otherwise the set $E$ would be measurable, since $(E \times E) \cap \Delta$ would be measurable and $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $x \mapsto (x,x)$ is continuous).

We need, in fact, stronger condtions:

1. $S$ is a separable metric space.
2. $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous for all $y \in T$.
3. $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is measurable for all $x \in S$.

Then $f$ is measurable. (Proof can be found in many standard books on measure theory.)

Comment: Isn't this a bit odd? I would hope for some more "symmetry" in statements $2$ and $3$.

Comment: You need a condition guaranteeing that the set can be written by finitely many steps using countable intersections or unions (therefore $S$ has to be separable and $x \mapsto f(x,y) continuous). There is no reason to expect a symmetric statement.